# How to disallow PHP file requests from outside web server on shared hosting

Tags: php, apache, http, file-permissions, web-hosting

In the situation where you have a Shared Hosting plan with a provider like GoDaddy without full access to the server, is there anything i can do to disallow outside HTTP requests for *.php files?

If anyone has experience with shared hosting or with GoDaddy specifically that would be appreciated. Im with GoDaddy and the only thing i can try is to mess with User/Group/World permissions of a php file, but no combinations enables server-only access to a file. And, obviously, i don't have access to the apache server's config file which is the easiest solution.

Comment: 700 the folder.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve.  If you don't want anyone to access your files, why are they on a host to begin with?

Comment: Do you have an access only for exposed directory on the server? I suggesting that any plan of any provider/hoster does have some amount of disk space and have specific directory structure where some of them exposed into the network. Just put your server-only scripts outside this directories.. May be I'm wrong..

Comment: place files outside web root- this is the standard approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**outside HTTP requests for *.php files**

I'll interpret this as requests from outside a set of people you're willing to share the pages with.  You want to limit access to your site.

Easiest approach -

Use an **.htaccess** file in DocumentRoot that limits access by IP address (if you are willing to force all the people who use the files to work from a limited set of IP addresses)

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

For Apache 2.2, in the **.htaccess** file, put

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 1.2.3.4
```

For Apache 2.4, use

```
Require ip 1.2.3.4
```

Another quick solution would be to password protect the directory with the .php files.  The configuration would look something like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
# (Following line optional)
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile "/usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords"
Require user goodguy
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html#lettingmorethanonepersonin

You may want to find hosting with SSH access to give you more control.